# Workaround for Salesforce issue W-13927439 preventing upload of a managed package

Tags: managed-package, patch

This [known Salesforce issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uWm3AAAS/%7E) (ref: W-13927439) is preventing us from uploading a patch to our 1G managed package.

The suggested temp workaround to "remove potential affected components from the package (PSG, Aura components) or any component which was recently added." is not applicable since in a patch version we can neither add nor remove components.

Has anyone found an actual workaround, or at least a way to identify which component may be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by:

- restoring several deleted public static methods
- removing a newly added static final property (also public)

With that I was able to successfully upload the release